# Using Backbone.js how i can ensure that all the app is loaded before any user interaction

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a web page that was developed using Backbonejs and Marionettejs.
I have a lot of views, the problem is when i enter for the first time to the app or i reload the webpage if i interact (make any click) in the page i think the page stops loading and i receive in the console error that can't navigate.
I tried to resolve this issue using requirejs or ensurejs but I had no success.
There is a way to ensure the web page is loaded completely  befor the user send an event or prevent the user to make that?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "page loaded" do you mean the DOM or actually downloaded the files?

To me it sound more like a routing issue. Try to double check if all the callback functions of the marionette router are specified and also the route you want to 
navigate to is avaiable.

If you mean the DOM, every **Marionette View** has **2 callbacks** about DOM rendering. The first one: **onRender** is called when the new HTML is ready to go in the DOM, but not appended yet and **onDomRefresh** is called when the new HTML is actually in the DOM. So, if you need to know when the page is rendered use onRender, when you also have to know if is in the DOM use onDomRefresh.

Like this:

```
var test = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
   onRender: function() { ... },
   onDomRefresh: function() { ... }
})
```

Require is to load files in a asynchronos way. You could definitely improve the architecture of your app.

Please add more details so i can give u a more specific answer.

I have also made a skeleton of a Backbone / Marionette / Require app. Check it out at: https://github.com/LucaMele/skeleton-marionette-require-gulp